# Text align is not working on same line

Tags: html, css

I am new I dont know more about code. I want one link on left side of a block and other link on right side. I am using the below command. Both are coming on the correct side but one in the new line. I have given the correct code in css but i think some html code problem. Please let me know the error in below.

```
       <div class="more">
       <span><a href="http://www.fe.com/discuss">See More</a></span>
       </div>
       <div class="placeadhere">
       <span><a href="http://www.fe.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=16">Place Ad Here</a></span>
       </div>
```

My CSS is

```
.more {
font-size:11px;
text-align:right;
margin:5px 0 10px 0;
```

}

```
.placeadhere {
font-size:11px;
text-align:left;
margin:5px 0 10px 0;
```

}

The image is 
[image]

THANKS YOU VERY MUCH MY PROBLEM SOLVE WITH YOUR ANSWERS... LOVE YOU AND SOF..

Comment: I have added css code also. Please check it.. thanks..

Comment: @user1820652 You can find the demo in my solution. Hope you understood the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem IS your css. You should paste that too.

```
<div class="more" style="width:auto; float: left;">
       <span><a href="http://www.fedri.com/discuss">See More</a></span>
</div>
<div class="placeadhere" style="width:auto; float: right;">
       <span><a href="http://www.fedri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=16">Place Ad Here</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Soo many answers all are working.... very good friends thanks you very very much... love you and SOF....

Answer (score 0):

Div's are **block** elements and will occupy the full width. Specify the div as **inline** so that it takes up only required width. OR you can make your div's positioning to absolute and float them as required.

```
.more {
 display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.placeadhere {
 display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 5px 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

See the working fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/bkgJT/

Comment: cdeez please can you let me know the code.. I dont know more of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this in working at http://cssdeck.com/labs/tztgz6hy/0

I added an additional div around your entire HTML fragment it should look like

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="more">
        <span>
            <a href="http://www.fedri.com/discuss">See More</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="placeadhere">
        <span>
            <a href="http://www.fedri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=16">Place Ad Here</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.more {
font-size:11px;
text-align:right;
margin:5px 0 10px 0;
}
.placeadhere {
font-size:11px;
text-align:left;
margin:5px 0 10px 0;
}
.main .more{float:left;}
.main .placeadhere{float:right;}
```

Comment: Soo many answers all are working.... very good friends thanks you very very much... love you and SOF....

Answer (score 0):

use this customize your div width

```
<div style="width:somevalue">
        <div class="more">
         <span><a href="http://www.fedri.com/discuss">See More</a></span>
       </div>
       <div class="placeadhere" style="float:right;">
        <span><a href="http://www.fedri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=16">Place Ad Here</a></span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Soo many answers all are working.... very good friends thanks you very very much... love you and SOF....

Comment: @user1820652 Remember you can upvote answers that helped you and also selecting the best answer by ticking it..

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float`

```
.more {
font-size:11px;
text-align:right;
margin:5px 0 10px 0; float:right
}

.placeadhere {
font-size:11px;
text-align:left;
margin:5px 0 10px 0; float:left
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd79a/)**